# WCF or plain old HttpWebRequest to communicate with JSPs?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, httpwebrequest

we have a third party web-based content management system written in Java. It has a SDK, a bunch of JSP calls that you can make which return XML.
Now I have to write a wrapper in .NET which will make these calls and return objects in place of XML. This will be a dll which can be added to .NET projects as any other external dlls.

What I want to know is that can it be done using WCF, which will not be a service btw, or am I good with plain HttpWebRequest?
If yes then please give pointers where I can get started with.

Regards.

Comment: re: *JSP calls that you can make which return XML* - show the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I get correct jsp is web services, right? There shouldn't be problems.

According to work WCF with different type of source you should check next articles:

- [Interoperability and Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730017)
- [Creating WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 Interoperable Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733080.aspx)

And you can check [Sun's Project Tango](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/glassfish/ProjectTango/) but it is related for complex solutions.